# Can you tell how many open disks are added together?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, characteristic-functions

As a disclaimer, I know the answer to this question; I'm sharing it here because I think others may enjoy tackling it.

(Notation: for $X\subseteq\Bbb R^2$, $~\mathbf1_X$ is the *indicator function* of $X$, defined by $p\mapsto\begin{cases}1,&p\in X\\0,&p\notin X\end{cases}$.)

Suppose $X_1,\dots,X_j$ and $Y_1,\dots,Y_k$ are subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$. Suppose also that $\sum_{i=1}^j\mathbf1_{X_i}=\sum_{i=1}^k\mathbf1_{Y_i}$. Must $j=k$?

Said another way, suppose $X_1,\dots,X_j$ are subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$, and $n_1,\dots,n_j$ are integers (or even reals). If $\sum_{i=1}^jn_i\mathbf1_{X_i}=0$, must $\sum_{i=1}^jn_i=0$?

Comment: As an aside, I really dislike the notation $\mathbf1_X$. The important bit, $X$, is shoved into a subscript. I _would_ use something like $[X]$, except that if $X$ were an interval (say $X=(0,1]$) then I'd be stuck writing $[(0,1]]$, and nobody wants that. \\ EDIT: Another alternative, I suppose, is to simply identify sets with $\{0,1\}$-valued functions and just write $X$. I'm not sure there is much opportunity for ambiguity. It also lets us write fun things like $X\cap Y=XY$ and $X\cup Y=X-XY+Y$.

Comment: @Aname $p$ ranges over $\Bbb R^2$. I could have written, "for all $p\in\Bbb R^2$, $~\sum_{i=1}^j\mathbf1_{X_i}(p)=\sum_{i=1}^k\mathbf1_{Y_i}(p)$", or "for all $p\in\Bbb R^2$, the number of $X_i$ that $p$ is in is the same as the number of $Y_i$ that $p$ is in". I'm not sure what you mean by "those things go up and up"?

Comment: @Aname The point from that one is that the $n_i$ could be _negative_. So instead of writing, eg, $\mathbf1_{X_1}+\mathbf1_{X_2}=\mathbf1_{Y_1}+\mathbf1_{Y_2}$, and asking if $2=2$, I could let $X_3=Y_1$, $~X_4=Y_2$, $~(n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4)=(1,1,-1,-1)$, and then say $(1)\mathbf1_{X_1}+(1)\mathbf1_{X_2}+(-1)\mathbf1_{X_3}+(-1)\mathbf1_{X_4}$ and ask if $1+1+(-1)+(-1)=0$.

Comment: @Aname Not sure I understand. If we drop the condition that they be homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$, then $\mathbf1_{X_1}+\mathbf1_{X_2}-\mathbf1_{X_3}=0$ becomes a possibility. It could happen if, say, $X_1\cup X_2=X_3$ and $X_1\cap X_2=\varnothing$. For an example, suppose they're subsets of a line, $X_1=(1,2]$, $~X_2=(2,3)$, and $X_3=(1,3)$ (using interval notation there to refer to half-open and open intervals).

Comment: @Aname But each $n_i$ is multiplying a different $\mathbf1_{X_i}$ term. Let's think of finite sets for a second. $(1)\mathbf1_{\{1,2\}}+(1)\mathbf1_{\{2,3\}}+(1)\mathbf1_{\{4\}}+(-1)\mathbf1_{\{1,2,3,4\}}+(-1)\mathbf1_{\{2\}}=0$, don’t you agree? Because each individual point gets added and subtracted an equal number of times. ($1$, $3$, and $4$ get added once and subtracted once, while $2$ gets added twice and subtracted twice.) But $\sum n_i=(1)+(1)+(1)+(-1)+(-1)\ne0$.

Comment: For the version with coefficients, we of course require $n_i \neq 0$.

Comment: @aschepler Do we? That would still have $\sum n_i=0$

Comment: Oh right, that version has the same $j$ on both sides.

Comment: @Aname If no one else solves it within a few days, I may post my solution. Until then, I will leave it as a puzzle.

Comment: From some sketches of various overlaps, it looks like if $f = \sum_{i=1}^j \mathbb{1}_{X_i} = \sum_{i=1}^k \mathbb{1}_{Y_i}$, and defining $A_i = \{ p \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid f(p) \geq i \}$, then $j = k = \sum_{i=1}^\infty (\dim H_{dR}^0(A_i) - \dim H_{dR}^1(A_i))$ where $H_{dR}$ are the de Rham cohomology groups. Not sure yet if this is straightforward to prove.

Comment: @aschepler The trick is that those summands need not all be finite, if for example $X_1\cap X_2$ has infinitely many connected components. (For "tame" sets, you're on the right track.)

Comment: @aschepler I posted my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a counterexample. This was as simple as I could make it; I don't know if there's a simpler solution.

In the first image, you have two open sets (red and black), so $j=2$; in the second, you have four (red, black, blue, and green), so $k=4$. Their sums are identical, including where the overlaps are, but $j\ne k$.

[image: Two sets]
[image: Four sets]

Note, by the way, that you cannot do this with only finitely many intersections. For example, look at how the frame crops the first image. It cuts the red set into three pieces, so in the finite part of the figure that fits into the frame, both images have four sets. It's only in the infinite that it becomes only two sets.

My original counterexample was a lot more complicated; this went through some rounds of revision.

Comment: We can ask a variant of this question, requiring that the sets be homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ rather than $\Bbb R^2$. We can solve it with a variation of this answer: https://imgur.com/a/KQVJpMt